# Bootstrap Glyphicons / Gotham Font Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, glyphicons

I've been working on this website: www.thekingsleygroup.co.uk

The Gotham font and Bootstrap Glyphicons were working fine before the site went live, but now aren't - could be the file paths as the files have moved onto a different server. But can't figure out what could need to be changed.

Any advice / help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I could see it working fine on the website

Comment: There is only one way to use Gotham legally on the web and that's through typography.com. Just an FYI. Voting to close since the issue can't be replicated. Loads fine for me.

Comment: Seems to work correctly in Safari, but not Chrome. Don't know if that is the same for you? Unless my browser is just caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the Mime-Types have been set correctly on the new server.